# Django telling me an existing template does not exist. | {% include %}

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to point to a template in Django which is not in the directory with which is the calling template is sitting in.

This is the relative path which has been copied and pasted here:

`static\libraries\templates\our-tech-stack.html`

```
Root
|
|---static
|   |
|   |--libaries
|      |
|      |--templates
|          |
|          |--<our-tech-stack.html>
|---templates
    |
    |--<calling-template.html>
```

This is the `include` in the `<calling-template.html>`

`{% include "../static/libraries/templates/our-tech-stack.html" %}`

This is the setup in my `settings.py`

```
'DIRS': [
            .
            ...
            ...
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/libraries/templates'),
            ...
            ...
            ...
            
        ],
```

As you can see this has been correctly set up, so why is Django telling me that the template does not exist when it very clearly does?

Read office documentation - however, the official documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A few things here, some of which are good practice, some of which are just how Django works,

1. Put html under your templates directory, not in static. Even if it is static pages.
2. Static files should be gathered into the same directory by running `python manage.py collectstatic`, although for local dev (i.e. `runserver`) they should also serve from any app folders.
3. Use the `{% load static  %}` tag in your templates, and then set a static file using `{% static 'path/to/file' %}` - this will handle both the dev server and live deployment after collectstatic is run.
4. `settings.py` should define `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` for consistent functionality between dev and production deployments.

Docs link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: Great, I will try this.

So in my calling template, I should use `{% load static '/libraries/templates/our-tech-stack.html' %}`? Unless I move the `our-tech-stack.html` template from the `static` folder to the `template` folder?

I gather this site has changed administrators since I last used this site. I'm getting some really good answers here lately. Normally I'd be treated like I murdered the admins cat for asking perfectly reasonable questions.

Comment: I think there's a difference between a "confused noob" question and an "I couldn't be bothered looking at the docs" question :)

Comment: @michnich very true. I'd rather be in the "confused noob" category any day!

Comment: Oh, and yes, I'd put any html into the templates folder, not the static folder. Static folders are for files that an html page will load as "extras" (images, css, js etc.)